# STM32 TIM2 changing prescaler in IRQ handler works strangely

Tags: stm32, timer

I am trying to change a prescaler in the timer interrupt handler, and I expected the new value would become active for the very next timer delay. I mean that after the handler exits, the timer will immediately run using the new prescaler value.

But what happens is that the next delay is the same as previous, then the updated prescaler is first used for delay after that. So, it looks like if I set prescaler value not for the next delay, but for the second one.

I would like to understand this strange behaviour and how can I change it.

I have tried with both 1 and 0 ARPE bit values in TIMx_CR1 with no difference.
Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S. I am using STM32F103C8T6 (black pill board).

General-purpose timer TIM2, and I use [STM32F1 RM0008 Reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/cd00171190-stm32f101xx-stm32f102xx-stm32f103xx-stm32f105xx-and-stm32f107xx-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) as a main resource.

---

Update: June 28, 2020

OK, I found it. I don't understand why and how it is working now, but I have found a way it works.

Here is a pseudocode of IRQ handler that did not work (works strangely):

```
reset UIF bit of TIMx_SR        (clear IRQ flag)
set UIDS bit of TIMx_CR1    (disable update)
write new prescaler value to TIMx_PSC
set the UG (Update generation) bit of the TIMx_EGR
reset UIDS bit of TIMx_CR1  (enable update)
```

and here the handler that works correctly (as I want it to):

```
reset CEN bit of the TIMx_CR1 (disable counter)
write new prescaler value to TIMx_PSC
set the UG (Update generation) bit of the TIMx_EGR
reset UIF bit of TIMx_SR        (clear IRQ flag)
set CEN bit of the TIMx_CR1 (enable counter)
```

If someone could explain what is the principal difference, and why the wrong one is wrong, it would be great. I am still standing on the hose.

Comment: There are dozens of STM32 chips and they all have few different timer types inside them. Would you be so kind to edit in which specific STM32 model you are using, and which specific timer instance inside it, so that we know what page of the which reference manual to open. Better yet, add a link to it too.

Comment: Thank you Justme, have edited my question.

Comment: Check the reference manual, but from memory the timer needs an update event to occur before using the new prescaler, that seems to fit your description too

Comment: Colin, you are right. But I explicitly set UG (Update generation) bit of the TIMx_EGR just after writing a new value to the TIMx_PSC register. And I can see in debugger it has been changed. But the next delay is equal to previous one. My new prescaler is always 'one interrupt too late'

Comment: @Thomas - Thanks for updating the question with the new results of your investigation. I have made small grammar edits to help readability (and added a link to the document you mentioned). One part which I didn't understand (and might not be useful to include) is that you say you are "*still standing on the hose*". If that point is important, can you change it to something easier to understand, please? It's not clear what is in that hose (I assume it's metaphorical) and why you need to prevent its flow. Do you mean something like "I don't like using solutions that I don't understand"? Thanks

Comment: Imagine you are watering your garden, you have opened a water tap, hold a hose in your hands, but the water does not flow. You do not understand what is the reason. But you don’t notice that you stepped on the hose. This is the meaning. You should not explain it to germans, but I thought it is an 'international' idiom. Sorry. I meant I still don't understand the problem.

Comment: @Thomas - Thanks for explaining! I now understand the meaning but I've never heard that idiom before, so I don't *think* it's an international one :-( Personally, I recommend you edit the question to say it more clearly, but it's your question, so it's your choice :-) Thanks again.